# What are the actions AccountController.SendCode and VerifyCode there for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5.2

This question pertains to the Visual Studio generated code that you get when you open an ASP.NET MVC application in Visual Studio Community 2015 RC.

In this generated code, what is the purpose of the actions `SendCode` and `VerifyCode` on the `AccountController`?

I have read their code but the time investment it requires to read this code and look up the meaning of the functions called within these from the MSDN -- all of which I have done -- and then open their views to see what they do, and then look for references of where they're called -- is too much for the benefit. Microsoft left so many comments in this generated code elsewhere. They could have left a few comments explaining the workflow of these actions and told us where they're meant to be (and are currently) called from.

One big reason for confusion is: these actions aren't called or redirected to from anywhere else.

Anyway, my understanding is that they're there to ask a visitor who has just registered on the website with his email address, to verify his email address by requesting that he be sent a code.

But then in the source code for the `SendCode` action, there's this drop-down in the code that gets the registered two-factor authentication providers in the View (which I have only seen by reading the code. I haven't been able to run this action because it isn't called from anywhere and I don't know how to get to it with the right arguments).

This leads me to suspect that this has to do with two-factor authentication by email and/or phone.

But two-factor authentication by phone is already covered in the `ManageController.AddPhone` action and the `ManagerController.EnableTwoFactorAuthentication`, right?

It seems like one needs an old priest and a young priest to understand what's in the generated code.

Could someone please tell me what these two actions are for and where are they (supposed to be) called from? What's the entire workflow for these two actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe these methods are in place if you wish to implement signup validation logic. For example, a user signs up to your website and you require them to validate their information (usually email address) before approving their signup.

So the flow would be:

1. User signs up
2. System creates user but doesn't activate account yet
3. System sends email to user email with validation link **(AccountController.SendCode())**
4. User opens email
5. User clicks validation link which navigates to validation page on your website
6. Page validates user information **(AccountController.CheckCode())**
7. If validation is successful, account is activated
8. If validation is not successful, error message is displayed

I'm not sure if you've seen [this post](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset) already but it outlines how you can implement something similar using SendGrid as your email provider.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for that article you linked to. I read that article just after posting the question.

Answer (score 2):

the purpose of sendcode and verifycode is in case you want to leverage MFA (multi factor authentication). hence, after login, you would be redirected to send code where you decide whether to send a code via i.e. mobile or email and once the code is sent, you get to verify code to enter the code you requested to complete the process.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Figured that out after a few hours of struggling with the code around the time I posted the question.